# Extract key from dictionary to add value to every dataframe element based on that key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, datetime

I have two lists of holidays and a dataframe that has rows with repeating dates. I need to add 0.5 to the `business_days` column for all of the days in the dataframe that are certain holidays. The two lists are:

```
["New Year's Day",
 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day',
 'Memorial Day',
 'Independence Day',
 'Labor Day',
 'Thanksgiving',
 'Christmas Day',
 "New Year's Day (Observed)",
 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day (Observed)',
 'Memorial Day (Observed)',
 'Independence Day (Observed)',
 'Labor Day (Observed)',
 'Thanksgiving (Observed)',
 'Christmas Day (Observed)']
```

and

```
2022-01-01 New Year's Day
2022-01-17 Martin Luther King Jr. Day
2022-02-21 Washington's Birthday
2022-05-30 Memorial Day
2022-06-19 Juneteenth National Independence Day
2022-06-20 Juneteenth National Independence Day (Observed)
2022-07-04 Independence Day
2022-09-05 Labor Day
2022-10-10 Columbus Day
2022-11-11 Veterans Day
2022-11-24 Thanksgiving
2022-12-25 Christmas Day
2022-12-26 Christmas Day (Observed)
```

The second one obtained via:

```
for name, date in holidays.US(years=2022).items():
    print(name, date)
```

`holidays.US` is a dictionary of datetimes (key) and names (value) of the holidays, so I would also need a way to access those dates

The df looks like this:

```
PredictionTargetDateEOM business_days
0       2018-10-31      23
1       2018-10-31      23
2       2018-10-31      23
3       2018-10-31      23
4       2018-10-31      23
        ... ... ...
172422  2022-09-30      21
172423  2022-09-30      21
172424  2022-09-30      21
172425  2022-09-30      21
172426  2022-09-30      21
```

For every holiday that is not in the first list but is in the second, I need to add 0.5 business days to the `business_days` column for each row of that specific date, and generalize this procedure to backfill historical data from previous years.

My idea is to extract the dates from the dictionary that generates the second list and match those up to the dates in the dataframe, and then add `0.5` to the `business_days` column for each row containing that date. I am at a bit of a loss for how to start on this process though, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sample input - first list

```
l1 = ["New Year's Day (Observed)",
 'Martin Luther King Jr. Day (Observed)',
 'Memorial Day (Observed)',
 'Independence Day (Observed)',
 'Labor Day (Observed)',
 'Thanksgiving (Observed)',
 'Christmas Day (Observed)']
```

second dictionary

```
d = {
"2022-01-01" :  "New Year's Day",
"2022-01-17" :  "Martin Luther King Jr. Day",
"2022-02-21" :  "Washington's Birthday",
"2022-05-30" :  "Memorial Day",
"2022-06-19" :  "Juneteenth National Independence Day",
"2022-06-20" :  "Juneteenth National Independence Day (Observed)",
"2022-07-04" :  "Independence Day",
"2022-09-05" :  "Labor Day",
"2022-10-10" :  "Columbus Day",
"2022-11-11" :  "Veterans Day",
"2022-11-24" :  "Thanksgiving",
"2022-12-25" :  "Christmas Day",
"2022-12-26" :  "Christmas Day (Observed)"
}
```

Sample input df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PredictionTargetDateEOM': ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-12-26", "2022-05-30"],
    'business_days' : [23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
})
```

Converting the dict to df

```
holidays_2_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "PredictionTargetDateEOM": d.keys(),
    "holidays": d.values()
})
```

Merge with first df (to find which rows match with holidays in second dict)

```
df = pd.merge(df, holidays_2_df, on=["PredictionTargetDateEOM"], how="left")
```

NaN rows are non-holidays and remaining rows are holidays (based on second dict).

Add the condition - not nan (holiday as per second) and negation of holiday in first list - subtract 0.5

```
df.loc[(df.holidays.notna()) & ~(df.holidays.isin(l1)), "business_days"] = df.loc[(df.holidays.notna()) & ~(df.holidays.isin(l1)), "business_days"] + 0.5
```

Sample result

```
PredictionTargetDateEOM business_days   holidays
0   2022-01-01  23.5    New Year's Day
1   2022-01-02  24.0    NaN
2   2022-01-03  25.0    NaN
3   2022-12-26  26.0    Christmas Day (Observed)
4   2022-05-30  27.5    Memorial Day
```

```
row index 0 - present in second and missing in first - added 0.5
row index 3 - present in both - didn't change
row index 4 - present in second and missing in first - added 0.5
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The only thing is the dictionary keys are datetime objects and not string. How could I convert those in order to allow the merge to proceed?

Comment: `df["PredictionTargetDateEOM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["PredictionTargetDateEOM])`

Comment: Okay cool, actually had to convert the `PredictionTargetDateEOM` in `holidays_2_df` to datetime

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but whole months are disappearing? Like when I run `df[df['PredictionTargetDateEOM']=='2022-10-31']` it's just an empty df. Oh, it may have to do with whether or not the word `(Observed)` is included in l1. Actually, the full list not included here has duplicates for each holiday without `(Observed)`, so it should work. Let me add that back in to my question. But also for months that are showing up with holidays too, like June or July, the business days are still the same--not showing the +0.5.

Comment: The `PredictionTargetDateEOM` should only be the last day of the month. So the `business_days` refer to the number of business days in that month, and should be the same for all the rows within that month.

Comment: can you raise a separate question for this. if the dates are going to change, the logic would be completely different

Comment: Hi Srinath, sure. I can do that. How should I change the question?

Comment: raise a new question

Comment: Here you go
https://stackoverflow.com/q/73169479/15975987