# Add quantity to pandas column if row condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this list of months `[11, 2, 6, 10]` and a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
PredictionTargetDateEOM business_days
0       2022-06-30      22
1       2022-06-30      22
2       2022-06-30      22
3       2022-06-30      22
4       2022-06-30      22
        ... ... ...
172422  2022-11-30      21
172423  2022-11-30      21
172424  2022-11-30      21
172425  2022-11-30      21
172426  2022-11-30      21
```

I need to check each row to see if the month in `PredictionTargetDateEOM` is in the list, and if so, add `0.5` to the `business_days` column for that row. The output would look like this:

```py
PredictionTargetDateEOM business_days
0       2022-06-30      22.5
1       2022-06-30      22.5
2       2022-06-30      22.5
3       2022-06-30      22.5
4       2022-06-30      22.5
        ... ... ...
172422  2022-11-30      21.5
172423  2022-11-30      21.5
172424  2022-11-30      21.5
172425  2022-11-30      21.5
172426  2022-11-30      21.5
```

Of course for rows in the dataframe with months not in the list, the number of business days for those rows should remain the same. I have tried these three methods to no avail:

```py
for row in predicted_df['PredictionTargetDateEOM']:
    if row.month in months:
        predicted_df['business_days'] += 0.5
```

^This one just sums up all of the values in `business_days`. I'm not sure how to select just the right row in the if statement. Would I use pandas `ix` attribute?

```py
predicted_df['business_days'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['business_days'] + 0.5 if x['PredictionTargetDateEOM'].month in months else x['business_days'], axis=1)
```

This one just gives me a blank dataframe.

```py
predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['PredictionTargetDateEOM'].month in months, 'final_business_days'] = #predicted_df['business_days']+0.5
```

The commented out section is because I don't know how to properly make this logic work, or if it is the right approach. I know this is how to set a new value, I don't know if I can use this logic to update an existing value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as your dates are datetime objects, you can use `.dt.month.isin()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'PredictionTargetDateEOM': ['2022-06-30', '2022-06-30'],
 'business_days': [22, 22]})

df['PredictionTargetDateEOM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PredictionTargetDateEOM'])

df.loc[df['PredictionTargetDateEOM'].dt.month.isin([11, 2, 6, 10]), 'business_days'] +=.5

print(df)
```

Output

```
  PredictionTargetDateEOM  business_days
0              2022-06-30           22.5
1              2022-06-30           22.5
```